# Word for unconventional performance in playing instruments?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, music

A whoa-dude performance performs by Salut Salon: [Competitive Foursome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKezUd_xw20):

[image]

It uses abnormal playing positions in the instruments, while keeping the high level of speed and accuracy of the music. It brings the joy to the audience.

What is this kind of performance called?

Comment: "Whoa-dude performance performs by Competitive Foursome". Which means?

Answer (score 3):

They call it

akrobatisch aus, und mit viel Humor

I'd call it a 'bravura' performance.

> Definition of **bravura** in English [(Oxford)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bravura)
>
> noun [mass noun] 1Great technical skill and brilliance shown in a
>   performance or activity:

Answer (score 0):

A gimmick. At least, that's what I'd call it.

Comment: Gimmick is a word for a cheap trick, with mildly negative overtones which sells the ladies shorter than their little black dresses are.                            "gimmick (ˈɡɪmɪk)
n
1. something designed to attract extra attention, interest, or publicity
2. any clever device, gadget, or stratagem, esp one used to deceive
3. (Theatre) US a device or trick of legerdemain that enables a magician to deceive the audience
[C20: originally US slang, of unknown origin]
ˈgimmickry n ˈgimmicky adj
Collins English Dictionary"

Answer (score 0):

[***avant-garde***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avant-garde) -

> a group of people who develop new and often very surprising ideas in art, literature, etc.

... though used in the adjectival sense.  It's somewhat neutral in judgement; not too positive or negative, though calling it a "new" idea is at least not a negative characterization.

Comment: a•vant-garde (əˌvɑntˈgɑrd, əˌvænt-, ˌæv ɑnt-, ˌɑ vɑnt-; Fr. a vɑ̃ˈgard) 

n.
1. the advance group in a field, esp. in the arts, whose works are unorthodox and experimental.
adj.
2. characteristic of or belonging to the avant-garde.
In this sense avant garde does not cover the performance at all, because it refers to the kind of music that is played, not the way it is eing played.

Comment: @JoostKiefte - I am reading the words you quoted for "adj. #2" and have to disagree completely, based both on what you wrote and my own knowledge of this term.  Is this term in your vocabulary, or are you relying on a dictionary?

Comment: From "in this sense" onwards it's my own description. Of course, as a(n amateur) musician and aficionado of classical music and (the older forms of) jazz I'm well acquainted with the term avant garde. The music the ladies play is not avant-garde at all (which new, unorthodox musical ideas would they be experimenting with?), the way they play their instruments isn't either, it's more a kind of trick depending on talent and an extremely well-developed ambidexterity

Comment: @JoostKiefte - you'd call it orthodox?  It sounds like you're perhaps confusing a genre with the adjective that shares the same term.  "Romantic" might cause you similar fits.  Musically, yeah, this is a parlor trick.  But this isn't musiccriticism.stackexchange.com

Comment: This performance does not concern any new and surprising ideas, musically or otherwise, so it's not avant-garde in that sense of the word. It is an astounding performance in a technical sense, but these things have been done before, so in that sense it is not avant-garde either, so as an answer to the question, avant-garde is unhelpful. I fail to understand your remark about "Romantic" and I certainly do not appreciate the abrasiveness of your tone.

Comment: @JoostKiefte - I'm being argumentative because you're splitting hairs over how novel the video's content is, and it seems irrelevant to a discussion of English vocabulary.  "There's nothing new under the sun" can be applied to nearly anything, and *avant-garde* becomes a useless term in the face of someone, somewhere, who insists it's all been done before.  I'm not going to un-suggest that you could call this *avant-garde*, especially as the OP termed it "unconventional."  I am providing what was asked for, not providing my own value judgement.

Comment: Okay, you stick with avant-garde then, I'll opt for bravura; I'm sure we can agree to differ.